# mathematica, Simplify trig function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

if say i have a function given :

```
               singlepattern = Cosh[theta] + Cosh[3theta]
```

How do i get a rational expression in terms of x of the function if i want to substitute Cosh[theta] by

```
               "Cosh[theta] = ( x )/ 2 "
```

expression?

Comment: Hi i'm trying to get a simplified rational expression for singlepattern in terms of x

Comment: Aren't rational expressions ratio's of polynomials? I don't directly see the relationship with your Cosh functions.

Comment: Well when you substitute the x/2 expression for cosh(theta) after doin simplepattern // ExpandTrig  ..... u will find that it will now have expressions in terms of x

Comment: You can also use a direct substitution of `theta->ArcCosh[x/2]`, coupled with `TrigExpand`. Like so: `Cosh[theta] + Cosh[3theta] /.theta->ArcCosh[x/2] // TrigExpand // Together`. This gives `(x^3-2*x)/2`. This, of course, is similar in spirit to Sjoerd's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I retagged the question as a homework. You should look into `ChebyshevT` polynomials. It has the property that `ChebyshevT[3, Cos[th] ]==Cos[3*th]`. So for your problem the answer is

```
In[236]:= x/2 + ChebyshevT[3, x/2]

Out[236]= -x + x^3/2
```

Alternatively, you could use `TrigExpand`:

```
In[237]:= Cos[th] + Cos[3*th] // TrigExpand

Out[237]= Cos[th] + Cos[th]^3 - 3 Cos[th] Sin[th]^2

In[238]:= % /. Sin[th]^2 -> 1 - Cos[th]^2 // Expand

Out[238]= -2 Cos[th] + 4 Cos[th]^3

In[239]:= % /. Cos[th] -> x/2

Out[239]= -x + x^3/2
```

---

**EDIT** The reason the above has to do with the explicit question, is that `Cosh[theta] == Cos[I*u]` for some `u`. And since `u` or `theta` are formal, results will hold true.

Comment: the function is `Cosh`, not `Cos`.

Comment: But this is the same, since `Cosh[u] == Cos[I*u]`, so it does not change the result of these calculations. Maybe I should edit my post to state that explicitly.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. It is in fact the same as Sjoerd's answer. I didn't see the `x/2` outside the parantheses in his answer and thought that you both had differing answers. my mistake and +1 to you :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `Solve` to solve for `theta`, then substitute, `Expand`, and `Simplify`:

```
In[16]:= TrigExpand[Cosh[3 theta] + Cosh[theta]] /. 
  Solve[Cosh[theta] == (x)/2, theta] // FullSimplify

During evaluation of In[16]:= Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve,
so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>

Out[16]= {1/2 x (-2 + x^2), 1/2 x (-2 + x^2)}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might interest you:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cosh%28x%29+%2B+cosh%283*x%29